# css error in overflow

Tags: css

i have some css issue . here is one link 
    http://way2enjoy.com/photos/viewstory/1132 when you will click on thumbnail the full photo will come in that 6 people likes is coming but the problem i am facing is when we click on 6 people likes link it is showing the persons who likes this but it is coming in background.i tried changing css classes but no luck.
when the users click on 6 people likes it should display the persons who liked over the open photo so if anyone can guide it will be a great help.

i tried 
    overflow

```
fixed

relative
```

but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `<div id="#facebox">` z-index to 101

Comment: hey you rocks what is the meaning of z-index please explain

Comment: @Steeve [Here is a comprehensive overview of z-index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/). Don't forget to accept the answer.